# continuous integration for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to develop a deployment pipeline CI for deep learning with automated test.

With which tools and framework can I develop this pipeline?

Comment: This question is "too broad"/"primarily opinion based"/"offtopic" for StackOverflow. However, I personally would *really like* to hear an answer for that question. Would it make sense to move it to [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It's not exactly about CI in its entirety, but I've decided to ask a related [question about build tools for Python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49631/build-tool-for-python-projects) on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. Before I send someone to SRSE, I decided to try some dogfooding...

Answer (score 1):

This is a big task, since there are so many things that can go wrong with a ML pipeline.  Here is a recent paper published out of Google that addresses this problem:  [ML test score](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45742.pdf)

Comment: That's a link-only answer to a paper that seems to be a collection of rather abstract scores, metrics, and general recommendations. It does not tell me *what* concrete tools to use.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin the apt-get install thing doesn't exist, afaik.  What, exactly, you end up doing will depend on what, exactly, you are working on.  Different ML products need different love and care.  Is your product unsupervised or supervised, for instance?  +1 If you create a useful and comprehensive apt-gettable thing for ML CI.

Comment: Ok, it's clear that all apps are different, but can you name at least *one* tool that is known to work well for python projects? E.g. [this page](https://www.fullstackpython.com/continuous-integration.html) tries to sell be Jenkins as a panacea. But I come from Java background, afair Jenkins on itself doesn't build anything, it needs Maven or Gradle as plug ins. I couldn't find an adequate replacement for python so far. For example, I've been struggling with the PyBuilder for days, and I still don't understand whether it's even used by anyone outside Immobilienscout.